# Crate download failure due to SSL certificate issue during Docker build

Tags: docker, ssl, rust, rust-cargo

I wrote a toy app in Rust mainly to play with a containerized Rust application.  I used the latest base image for Rust.  My Docker build fails with the following error -

```
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to get `chrono` as a dependency of package `timeserver v0.1.0 (/timeserver)`

Caused by:
  failed to query replaced source registry `crates-io`

Caused by:
  download of config.json failed

Caused by:
  failed to download from `https://index.crates.io/config.json`

Caused by:
  [60] SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK (SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

Here is my simple Rust code -

```rust
use chrono::prelude::*;
use warp::Filter;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // Match any request and return the current date and time
    let routes = warp::any().map(|| {
        let local_date_time: DateTime<Local> = Local::now();
        let response: String = format!("Hello from Rust at {}", local_date_time);
        response
    });

    warp::serve(routes).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030)).await;
}
```

Here is my Cargo.toml -

```yaml
[package]
name = "timeserver"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
chrono = { version = "0.4.26", features = ["serde"] }
tokio = { version = "1.29.1", features = ["full"] }
warp = "0.3.5"
```

And here is the Dockerfile -

```
FROM rust:1.71 as build

# Create a new empty shell project
RUN USER=root cargo new --bin timeserver
WORKDIR /timeserver

# Copy over the manifests
COPY ./Cargo.lock ./Cargo.lock
COPY ./Cargo.toml ./Cargo.toml

# This build step will cache the dependencies
RUN cargo build --release
RUN rm src/*.rs

# Copy the source tree
COPY ./src ./src

# Build for release
RUN rm ./target/release/deps/timeserver*
RUN cargo build --release

# The final base
FROM rust:1.71-slim-buster

# Copy the build artifact from the build stage
COPY --from=build /timeserver/target/release/timeserver .

EXPOSE 3030

# Set the startup command to run the binary
CMD ["./timeserver"]
```

I have tried with an older Docker version `1.61` too but encountered the same issue.  Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Are you in a corporate network?

Comment: Yes I am.  But I don't think it's a network issue as I can build and run the app fine as a normal app (that is outside Docker).

Comment: Is 'outside Docker' Windows? Organizations with centrally-managed (i.e. domain-joined) Windows systems often set up an SSL interceptor and 'push' its cert to the Windows machines, so most Windows programs accept the interceptor's certs even though they are actually fake (except Firefox, and even that if 'enterprise integration' is turned on) -- but your docker image/container doesn't. It is technically possible to similarly nobble Linux or Unix systems, but much less common. (@aled)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 that was my thinking.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  No it's Mac OS.